# Get a radio button value from a .qml file using PyQt 5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

How can I get the radio button value from a .qml file using PyQt 5?

The .qml file is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"

    RadioButton {
        id: button1
        text: "1"
        objectName: "radio_button"
    }

    TextInput {
        id: text_input
        objectName: "Textinput"
        x:300
        y:300
        width: 80
        height: 20
    }

    Button {
        id: button_execute
        x: 158
        y: 341
        width: 211
        height: 36
        text: qsTr("Execute")
        onClicked: {
            con.on_execute()
        }
    }
}
```

The Python code for reading this .qml file is as follows:

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot


class Bridge(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_execute(self):
        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
        # This will give me the value of text input
        text_val = win.findChild(QObject, "Textinput").property("text")
        # How to get the radio button value if it's checked or not checked?

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Reading the qml file
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    bridge = Bridge()
    context.setContextProperty("con", bridge)
    qmlFile = join(dirname(__file__), 'qml_test_1.qml')
    engine.load(abspath(qmlFile))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I know if the radio button is checked or not? I tried using objectName. But that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use object names. It is bad practice. Use signals and slots or models.

---

##### Example:

File *main.py*

```py
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot


class App(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.current_rb_text = ""

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def set_current_rb_text(self, text: str):
        self.current_rb_text = text

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_execute(self):
        print(self.current_rb_text)

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Reading the qml file
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    bridge = App()
    context.setContextProperty("App", bridge)
    qmlFile = join(dirname(__file__), 'main.qml')
    engine.load(abspath(qmlFile))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

File *MyRadioButton.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


RadioButton {id:btn
    onClicked:App.set_current_rb_text(btn.text)
}
```

File *main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"

    ColumnLayout{
        MyRadioButton {
            id: button1
            text: "1"
            objectName: "radio_button"
        }

        MyRadioButton {
            id: button2
            text: "2"
            objectName: "radio_button"
        }

        MyRadioButton {
            id: button3
            text: "3"
            objectName: "radio_button"
        }
    }

    TextInput {
        id: text_input
        objectName: "Textinput"
        x:300
        y:300
        width: 80
        height: 20
    }

    Button {
        id: button_execute
        x: 158
        y: 341
        width: 211
        height: 36
        text: qsTr("Execute")
        onClicked: {
             App.on_execute()
        }
    }

}
```

Note:

I recommend you to use PySide6.3 since it is the official Qt binding and it has better support for [QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML). For instance, here you could have just declared a property in Python and bind it to the radio button text.